# Good reference on higher dimensional derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, derivatives

I've spent several months now periodically scouring the internet for a comprehensive overview of an introduction to higher dimensional derivatives.  I've already read baby Rudin's section on the topic, but I'm looking for an online resource or discussion on the topic that explains the higher dimensional derivative intuitively.

Does anyone have any links to online sources?  I've already found quite a few good ones (including one from **math insight**), but none of them really lay it out from the very beginning.

For example, none of them explain how the second partial derivatives being continuous is equivalent the the first partial derivatives of the total derivative being continuous (since either of these criteria can be used to show a function has a second total derivative).

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: If two statements imply the same result, we cannot necessarily conclude that the two statements are equivalent.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ok, that's true, but I think they are equivalent anyway.  I'd like to see a discussion of this somewhere so I can understand what's going on.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by the total derivative? A definition compatible with Rudin differs meaningfully from its presentation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative), for example.

Comment: Would you say, for example, that the total derivative of $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ would be the gradient $\nabla f$ of $f$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The total derivative of $f$ is a map that assigns to each element in $\Bbb R^{n}$ a linear map.

Comment: The two statements are, in fact, equivalent.  [This page](http://mathinsight.org/derivative_matrix) from math insight gets you a part of the way there, but  I could understand how you might be getting tripped up on the distinction between a matrix and a linear map.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

No reference here, but I can at least answer your direct question of why the two conditions are equivalent.  In particular, we need to figure out what the "first partial derivatives of the total derivative" look like.

Assume, for the time being, that we're talking about a function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$.  The total derivative is given by
$$
Df = \pmatrix{f_{x_1} & \cdots & f_{x_n}}
$$
The *partial derivatives* of this matrix are given by
$$
(Df)_{x_j} = \pmatrix{f_{x_1x_j} & \cdots & f_{x_nx_j}}
$$
Now, we need to note that a matrix of functions is continuous if and only if each of its entries is continuous. In particular, $(Df)_{x_j}$ is continuous if and only if for each $i$, the $i$th entry of $(Df)_{x_j}$ is continuous.  That is, $(Df)_{x_j}$ is continuous if and only if for each $i$,
$f_{x_ix_j}$ is continuous.

Now, we have directly shown that the partial derivatives of $Df$ are continuous if and only if the second partial derivatives of $f$ are continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the easy proof.  I saw another proof earlier that was much more complicated, dealing with $L(\Bbb R^{n}, \Bbb R)$.